# Schematic Reading - Fluid Control Limit Switch Question

Tags: mechanical-engineering, sensors, pistons

Does limit switch **LS1** remain pressed on until the piston moves to **LS2**?[image: Limit switches are shown as 1 and 2]

Comment: Is this a logic problem? Please provide more detail and background. It may also be helpful to provide your thought process so far.

Comment: I understood it like in this way. Is it correct? **"If we are using a roller type lever for the limit switch, it will be pushed forward when the piston moves forward and it will remain in that position until the piston returns to its original position"**

Comment: What does the documentation say? Can you just call the manufacturer and ask an engineer?

Comment: @GisMofx This is included in a tutorial and it is not explained in it. If it's a **roller type** is my assumption correct?

Comment: From the diagram, it looks to me like limit switch one will only be engaged when the piston is retracted, and limit switch 2 will be engaged when the piston is fully extended. When the piston is anywhere in between 1 and 2, i would expect neither limit switch to be activated.

Comment: @Ethan48 Thanks. That's what I wanted to know.

Comment: To everyone voting to close, I think it's a valid question about how to properly understand the conventions of hydraulic schematics. Maybe it sounded like a request to analyse the circuit without enough info, but I'm pretty sure it's just about how to read it.

Comment: @ethan48 that may be true, but that is valuable information to include in the question!

Comment: @AnnaClarke, Is it possible strengthen the question by adding more content. A link to the tutorial referenced in comments might be a good start. It is the communities opinion that their insufficient information to formulated a good response, thus the question is in danger of been closed. I personally believe the question is a reasonably good questions. But I am only one voice.

Comment: Based on the diagram, it would also seem that limit switch 2 is adjustable based on that ruler-like drawing on the schematic. Also, upon closer inspection, I don't see anything in Limit Switch 2 that would Control Limit Switch 1. I, also, would second that the limit switched are only activated when the piston is in a limit position.